# Group lines of code in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it was possible to group lines of code in vba excel, in order to make the view more pleasant. Meaning I have 1000 lines of code and would like to group lines in order to hide/show them. I know this is possible in other coding languages, so I would like to know if it was possible in vba.
Thanks

Comment: If you have 1000 lines of code in one procedure, you should rewrite it.  But if that 1000 lines is spread over multiple procedures (which I assume is what you have) there **is** an option to just display a single procedure (uncheck "Default to Full Module View" in Options) at a time.  Not as good as being able to expand/collapse code in IDEs such as Visual Studio, but I think it is the closest you are going to get without a 3rd party add-in.

Comment: This feature is often referred to as *Code Folding*, but is unavailable in the VBE. It's not yet in the Ruberduck VBA add-in, but it is on the roadmap.

Comment: @YowE3K WPF for Tearable tabs, dockable windows, code-folding, squiggly lines, Intellisense, Status Bar.... It's a big job, but it *has* to be done....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, not out of the box. There is an open source tool that will be able to do this in a future release http://rubberduckvba.com/

If you have a lengthy procedure you may what to ask yourself if it does more than one thing. As a general rule, a procedure should only do one thing. If you break up each separate "thing" into individual procedures, then you can call each procedure in a parent subroutine. A good book on this is "[Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)"

```
Sub ParentSub()
  ChildSub1()
  ChildSub2()
End Sub
```

Comment: Rubberduck doesn't support it *yet*.... It's on the roadmap with AvalonEdit code-panes...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to breaking code up (refactoring) into smaller logical functions, you can also break them across different modules if the `Private/Public` setting allows it.

If your code is in a class (or in a worksheet), then you can also use `Friend` for your functions/subroutines.

Of course, once refactored, I often find that I build classes to make my code simpler and easier to maintain. This allows you to hide (encapsulate) much of your lower level code and your main program is now at a much higher level and sometimes almost (if you squint hard enough and you have named your classes and methods properly) look like readable English!

As an aside, the `Call` keyword is not recommended unless the called expression does not start with an identifier ([MSDN ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/call-statement)).  In the answer above, the following will work quite fine.

```
Sub ParentSub()
  ChildSub1()
  ChildSub2()
End Sub
```